# Get Value from Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show a `Dialog` with an `EditText`. I envision it having two buttons: a positive button, which will persist the text contained in the `EditText`, and a negative button, which will cancel and return to the `Activity` that launched it as if nothing had happened. I have tried using an `AlertDialog` with no success:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(context);
final EditText text = new EditText(context);

builder.setTitle("New Profile").setMessage("Name this new profile").setView(text);
builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
        final String name = text.getText().toString();
        //do something with it
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
    }
});
builder.create().show();
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `setView()` method? Would using a custom `Dialog` be more practical?

**EDIT:**

I've gotten several answers saying the code works for them... not sure why it isn't working for me. Here's the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  326): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at com.gobernador.TopPage.onListItemClick(TopPage.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is this failing? Is it not properly getting the text from the EditText text? Or is the dialog not showing?

Comment: your code is working i just checked, what issues you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gobernador  Agarwal is right , i also tried you code and it was working  , try it by replacing context with **this**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        final EditText text = new EditText(this);

        builder.setTitle("New Profile").setMessage("Name this new profile").setView(text);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                final String name = text.getText().toString();
                //do something with it
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```

Comment: The difference was a disparity between the Application context and the Activity context. Future readers of this post, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343666/1210260) for more information on why this was the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.setTitle("Title");
         alert.setMessage("Message");
        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
       final EditText input = new EditText(this);
       alert.setView(input);
       alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String value = input.getText();
                 // Do something with value!
       }
       });

      alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             // Canceled.
      }
     });

     alert.show();
```

Comment: doesnt input.getText() return an Editable and not a String?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom dialog instead of `AlertDialog` like this

```
Dialog dilog=new Dialog(this);
dilog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dilog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout_in_xml);
```

and refer to its field

```
EditText youredittext=(EditText)dilog.findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
String textGet = youredittext.getText().toString(); // u will get ur inserted stting here

dilog.show() to show it
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your custom view within the dialog. You can either create the view dynamically or inflate it from XML. The method you will want to use instead of *setTitle*, *setNegativeButton*, etc is [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29).