# "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, android-alertdialog

I want show AlertDialog when i will send mail. But I have this Exception. `WindowManager$BadTokenException` what does it mean?

```
pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.sContext , "", "Sending Mail...", true);

    RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
```

Comment: Post logcat error as well as more code ... to understand your problm

Comment: what is MainActivity.sContext? if it is getApplicationContext(), change it to "this" or "MainActivity.this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question the problem is that you are trying to update the UI on a different thread, and that isn't possible. The `RetreiveFeedTask` is probably executing on a different thread.

You have to run your code to dispay an alertdialog on the UI thread. You can do that by pasting the following code in your own code and add the code in the body of the method `run()`.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Activity is closed and you are trying to do some work with your `ProgressDialog`

You can handle it by using `onPause` method

For example

```
protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
         if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing())
             pDialog.dismiss();
         pDialog = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`BadTokenException`: You cannot display an `Dialog` through a `Context` that is not an `Activity`.

Use:

```
ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Sending Mail...", true);
```

See: [BadTokenException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343393/603270)